# error: 'nanf' is not a member of 'std' when building tensorflow android with quantized graph

Tags: android, linux, c++11, android-ndk, tensorflow

I'm trying to build google android example using my own graph.
I used the quantization method explained [here](https://petewarden.com/2016/05/03/how-to-quantize-neural-networks-with-tensorflow/).
I've added "//tensorflow/contrib/quantization:cc_ops" and "//tensorflow/contrib/quantization/kernels:quantized_ops" to the build file.
When I run `bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo`
I get the following error`ERROR: /home/dani/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1065:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core:gpu_runtime' failed: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc failed: error executing command external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables ... (remaining 95 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.cc: In member function 'virtual void* tensorflow::GPUNanResetAllocator::AllocateRaw(std::size_t, std::size_t)':
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.cc:169:53: error: 'nanf' is not a member of 'std'
   std::vector<float> nans(req_size / sizeof(float), std::nanf(""));
                                                     ^
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.cc:169:53: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/cmath:44:0,
                 from external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/complex:44,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/numeric_types.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:24,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/visitable_allocator.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.h:23,
                 from tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.cc:16:
external/androidndk/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/math.h:354:7: note:   'nanf'
 float nanf(const char *) __NDK_FPABI_MATH__ __pure2;
       ^
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.cc: In member function 'virtual void tensorflow::GPUNanResetAllocator::DeallocateRaw(void*)':
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.cc:182:53: error: 'nanf' is not a member of 'std'
   std::vector<float> nans(req_size / sizeof(float), std::nanf(""));
                                                     ^
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.cc:182:53: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/cmath:44:0,
                 from external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/complex:44,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/numeric_types.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:24,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/visitable_allocator.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.h:23,
                 from tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.cc:16:
external/androidndk/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/math.h:354:7: note:   'nanf'
 float nanf(const char *) __NDK_FPABI_MATH__ __pure2;
       ^
Target //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo failed to build`
I've tried using both `android-ndk-r10e` and `android-ndk-r11`.
Thanks, Dan

Comment: Without any code to see, I have to ask: do you #include <cmath>?

Comment: This is strange, because the Android demo shouldn't depend on that file. Can you run `bazel query 'somepath(//tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo, //tensorflow/core:common_runtime/gpu/gpu_debug_allocator.cc)'` and report the result here? (I get "Empty results" when I run it on the most recent build.)